# How to generate a code made of 4 hex digits in C?

Tags: c

How to generate a code made of 4 hex digits?
 the code meets the following conditions:
-first and third digits are the same
-second digit is even
-third digit is larger than 9
-fourth digit is random (has no conditions)

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this problem? Is it how to generate a random number? How to take constraints into consideration? How to connect the 4 digits to a single number?

Comment: I don't know how to start. For example I don't know how to generate a hex digit !

Comment: Can you solve the problem for generating 4 *numbers* in range `[0,16)` each that fulfills the constraints? Do you know how to generate a random number in `[0,16)`? At least show us you tried something

Comment: @amit I know to generate a number between 0 and 16 using the random function. n=random(16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
  int code1, code2, code4;
  srand(time(NULL)); // set random seed
  code1 = random()%6+10;   // random between 10 and 15
  code2 = random()%8*2;    // even
  code4 = random()%16;     // random between 0-15
  printf("%X%X%X%X\n",code1, code2, code1, code4);
}
```

There are a few things to note here. The first is that I generate 3 'codes', since the third is always the same as the first.

To generate a random number from 0-15, use `random()%16`  I am using type `int` to store these, it may not matter. When printing, I use `%X` and not the more common `%d`, as `%X` will print it in hex. I print four hex digits (reusing code1 of course).
The final part is to meet your conditions. 
code1 is a random number in the range 0-5 and adds 10 to it (making it greater than 9)
code2 is `random()%8*2` which generates a random number in the range 0-7 and then doubles it (making it even)
code4 is just a random number from 0-15

You did not explain what to do with the generated code, so I just printed it. You could use the `sprintf` function if you need to print it into a string for further work.

Comment: For me gcc wanted rand() from stdlib.h.

Comment: Yes, that is why I included stdlib.h :P

Comment: What I mean is, with default settings random() is hidden behind macros in gcc stdlib.h, but rand() is not.

Comment: @Innovine How to store the number generated in a number... ?

Comment: Hex numbers are nothing special, you can deal with them the same way as regular numbers (note how I used an int to hold the hex). You could try (not tested!) int result = code1*16*16*16 + code2*16*16 + code1*16 + code4;    If this seems mystic, compare it to how you would take the numbers 1, 2 and 3 and get 123 in base 10, 1*10*10 + 2*10 + 3

Comment: And if you are curious, this multiplying by 16 to 'move' the digit to the right place is known as shifting, and C and C++ have built in ways to do this exact thing. It's faster than multiplying and easier when you understand it, but I don't want to confuse you with too many things at once. Look it up if you are curious, it would certainly help with understanding hex and number representations and this kind of work